# Unable to resolve module ./zlib_bindings

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, node-modules, zlib

We are working on an customised react native app using rocketchat sdk  node module. When we are running the app it is giving the below error :

zlib added using

```
npm i zlib —-save
```

> error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./zlib_bindings from
> /projectpath/rocketchatsampleclient/node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js:
> None of these files exist:   *
> node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib_bindings(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
>
> - node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib_bindings/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
>
> > 1 | module.exports = require('./zlib_bindings');

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it is a node module built for node applications and not for react native application. So, i replaced it with the node module built for react native application. I replaced the rocket chat sdk package built for react native and that fixed all the problems.

Comment: What did you install specifically? This would be helpful if you wrote what package you used instead.